# How to read wordpress cookies in my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, cookies

I want to integrate my website with wordpress.I want to know as to how can i read wordpress cookies so that i dont need to authenticate users again in my website.I tried including the header file of wordpress in my website, but then i was unable to connect to the database of my website.Both of which are different.Can i set additional parameters of cookies like user level,etc?My website is written in php.

Comment: Including the WP header file is probably the very best way. I would recommend looking into the compatibility problem again - it should be possible to have a WP DB connection, and some other connection, in the same script.

Comment: Is your website operating on the same (sub)domain as the WP site? If so, just look into the $_COOKIE array and the WP cookie(s) will be in there. If you're on a different domain, then it's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

In your website, include that code at the top of each files :

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

...assuming your blog is in `./blog/`.

It includes the whole wordpress stack. You will have access to all wordpress functions in your code. With that you can easily check if user is logged in, roles and capabilities, but also retrieve posts or so.

Then in you code, to check user :

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) { ... }
```

[Codex : is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

You can also include a logout link :

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout/">Logout</a>
```

If your blog and your site are not on the same domain or subdomain, you have to customize cookie domain in `wp-config.php`

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'); // Share cookie on all subdomains
```

### **EDIT**

If you really just want to read the wordpress cookies (which is a good choice for performance) : the cookie name is stored in a constant AUTH_COOKIE.

AUTH_COOKIE is defined in `/wp-includes/default-constants.php -> line 171` as

```
"wordpress_" + md5( get_site_option(siteurl) )
```

You have to retrieve or recompute AUTH_COOKIE then read $_COOKIE[AUTH_COOKIE].

To parse it, look at `wp_parse_auth_cookie()` in `wp-includes/pluggable.php @line 585`
(indeed the format is simple `user|expiration|hmac` so split the chain by `|` and get the first element)

Comment: But if i include wordpress header in my website pages, then i am unable to connect to my own database.Website and blog are in the same domain. Is there any way to read the cookie without using the header?

Comment: There is no reason that you can't connect to your DB, unless perhaps your hosting provider limit your DB connection. I doubt, since you say that these are two different DB. But see my edit for the other way...

Comment: @Artimuz I am usind jquery uploadify, to upload files from a wordpress page. I have tried first with `include_once '../../../../wp-load.php';` then with the code you recommended,  but still `is_user_logged_in()` returns false. It looks to me more like a wordpress bug.

Comment: typed uploadify php script in browser, and it worked... so guess it's an uploadify bug somewhere.

Comment: I posted a soultion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146667/how-can-i-get-the-current-logged-in-user-with-wordpress-shortinit/52985199#52985199 that might be helpful if your obectives are to make things easy for 1.05 sek.

Answer (score -1):

To make cookies work in Wordpress you need to set it special way like so in functions.php

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('sitename_newvisitor', 1, time()+1209600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

So the important point is
`setcookie('sitename_newvisitor', 1, time()+1209600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);`

To get it

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
     echo 'Welcome back!';
}
else {
     echo 'Hello new visitor!';
}
```

**Note**: You can change cookie name 'sitename_newvisitor', value, timeout, COOKIEPATH and COOKIE_DOMAIN to fit your needs