# How Can I Get the Current Logged-In User with WordPress SHORTINIT

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm running a PHP script called by an AJAX function. I do not want to use the built-in WordPress AJAX API because it would take way too long, since I'm uploading a lot of images. I'm using SHORTINIT to do a partial WordPress load like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173002/how-declare-ajax-functions-ussing-shortinit

I need to check the username of the current logged-in user. Can someone list the files I need to include/require in my custom PHP file and the order they should be in? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I cant comment (new user). The final soultion (single WP install) I use for making `is_user_logged_in()` and `current_user_can()` work, is as follow below. We `require('wp-load.php')` **first** *(to skip wp() in load-blog-header.php)*, and get `ABSPATH` constant then, manually includes **exactly** all the stuff needed.

Using `define('SHORTINIT', true)` + `require('wp-load.php')` + manually includes:

Pageload: **1.05 sek** - included files: **43 files**

Comparing: Using **ONLY** `require('wp-load.php')`:

Pageload: **1.35 sek** - included files: **419 files**

The time difference (0.3 sek) might differ from installs and PHP engines, but while validating many requests on one pageload -things adds up!

Remember to use relative call to WP installed dir. From a Wordpress custom plugin dir, inside one subdir level, normal install, a path should be like:

```
$wordpress = '../../../../wp-load.php';
```

Then:

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
include_once $wordpress;

require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-roles.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-role.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-session-tokens.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php' );
//require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/query.php' ); // - might be useful
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );

wp_cookie_constants();

require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/vars.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/kses.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rest-api.php' );
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' );
```

After this, user validation is accessable. For other task, r*unning on one or two requests*, tracking down other needed files is not worth 0.3 sek. Skip the `SHORTINIT` constant and manually clutter.

Comment: Great to clear the time and counted files out. Also confirm that this solution works from a plugin like: ´h**p://localhost/subdir-installed-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-plugin/files/downloads.php´

Comment: Not working anymore since WP 6.1 (user not logged in anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but I will post it here so it might be useful to other people.

I needed a quick light weight way to load the minimum of Wordpress to figure out the user in a separate API next to the Wordpress install. For me this code works with Wordpress 4.8

*NOTE: it is only used in this way. It can be that if you need to do more Wordpress things, you are missing some includes.*

```
// load minimum wordpress to load the user
define('SHORTINIT', true);

/** Define ABSPATH as this files directory */
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );

//WP config file
require ('wp-config.php');

// Run the installer if WordPress is not installed.
wp_not_installed();

require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-roles.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-role.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-session-tokens.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php' );

require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/query.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );

// Define constants after multisite is loaded. Cookie-related constants may be overridden in ms_network_cookies().
wp_cookie_constants( );

// Create common globals.
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/vars.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/kses.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rest-api.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' );
require('wp-load.php');

$user = wp_get_current_user();
var_dump($user);
```

I used the code here as a starting point but that didn't work under the current Wordpress version for me:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28342/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-wordpress-users-but-without-loading-the-entire-wordpre